# Why is my music becoming corrupted on my PS Vita?

Tags: ps-vita

It's pretty much self-explanatory: the music on my PS Vita keeps becoming corrupted.

This morning, I had 142 songs, but now I only have 138, and it may not seem like much, but it is.

I mean, it was all good in the beginning, had all my music. It was chill. Then, I saw a corrupted file. No biggie; just delete it. Well, it *was* a biggie. As the day progressed, more files got corrupted and I deleted them.

I don't even know what songs I'm missing.

I haven't taken this SD card out without turning my PS Vita all the way off, first. I haven't tinkered with anything that might've messed it up. I don't know what happened.

So, why is my music becoming corrupted, and how do I stop/fix it??

Comment: How old is the SD card?

Comment: It can't be that old. I only got my first PS Vita in December 2014. Got the SD card a few months after that. So about a year, but I don't use this SD card much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the why, there are a multitude of things that can corrupt data. The more important thing is to fix it.

When experiencing data corruption issues on the Vita, step one is always to perform a database rebuild. This is accomplished via the system recovery menu. To reach this menu, power off your Vita and turn it back on while holding R and the PS button. It will boot into safe mode and when the menu appears, you're going to select the second option: Rebuild Database. This solves the vast majority of corruption issues.

Make sure it's plugged into AC power as this operation can take a while depending on the size of your card and how much data is on it.

Comment: Will rebuilding the database erase any of my game data, or other content?

Comment: Rebuilding a database isn't going to overwrite any data unless it's so corrupt that the system can't recognize it. Just to be sure, you can always back your card up before rebuilding the data structures.